# Load other architectView Wikitude

Tags: wikitude

Im trying load other architectView in my proyect. I have one with markers and I want other with only radar but always load the first architectView with markers. I call the functions in the same class. Im using Wikitude SimpleARBrowser example from Wikitude 2.0. Thanks for your help

EDIT:

I call this.architectView.load("index.html") in SimplebrowserActivity with other methods show the markers in the view. After I started other activity and I call again SimplebrowserActivity  with other function to load this.architectView.load("index2.html") but the activity load index.html not index2.html

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the problems you're facing? What have you tried so far? What kind of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the Wiktidue SDK (as of 3.2) does not support creating more than 1 ArchitectView at a time. You need to reuse it or destroy the current and create one anew.